# how to place a print button icon on extjs modal window along with the other config propertie

Tags: extjs

I am having a extjs modal window i want to  put a print button on modal hear to print the window content. Some how i am not able to align it with the other config properties. Here is my code. Print button always comes to the secondline
see the attached iamge[Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APuQH.png).

Is there better way to align the print button with the modal header?

```
 var modal = function(Exturl) {
var ImageModalWin = new Ext.Window(
        {
            modal : true,
            border : false,
            plain : true,
            maximizable : true,
            scrollable : true,
            monitorResize : true,
            items : {
                xtype : 'button',   
                iconCls : 'fa fa-print',
                iconMask : true,
                listeners : {
                    click : function() {
                        var divToPrint = document.getElementById('imgId');
                        var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');

                        newWin.document.open();

                        newWin.document
                                .write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'
                                        + divToPrint.innerHTML
                                        + '</body></html>');
                        newWin.document.close();

                        setTimeout(function() {
                            newWin.close();
                        }, 10);

                    }
                }

            },
            html : '<div id="imgId" class="to-print" style="width:100%;height:100%;"><center><img src="'
                    + url + '"></center></div>',
            resizable : {
                preserveAspectRatio : true
            }
        });
ImageModalWin.show();
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything from `items` is always shown in the content area, never in the header area of the window. If you add objects to the `items` config of the `header` config, they are added to the header, and also the `tools` property contents are added there.

Eventually, your code is really complicated, as there is a builtin (ExtJS) way of adding a print "button" to the header, which you will stumble upon (as it's the only result) when you search the ExtJS (6.0.1 classic) docs for "print".

Try it:

```
xtype:'window',
tools:[{
    type:'print',
    handler:function() {
        ...
    }
}]
```